# If i use 301 redirects (to bounce the requests), will the other destination be aware of my Server IP?

Tags: security, http-headers, redirect, http-status-code-301

(Just for the knowledge)

I wonder, let's say one day, when my Site is suddenly having some attacks at the login page (e.g: `/login.php`). If i don't bother about my Login page anymore, and i want to redirect these incoming attempts to (let's say) ---> [www.google.com](https://www.google.com) (by using 301 redirects).

Of course then all these kinda illegal attempts will be redirected to Google. And Google will react something on them (their IPs). Then my question is:

- Will my Server IP also be **black listed**? Or at any risk? (Because i'm the one who redirecting to them.)
- Or is it legitimate to do?

Just for the knowledge. Thanks all :)

Answer (score 1):

It is legitimate to do so, you just tell the client to gtfo your website and instead visit Google.
You should consider using a 302 Redirect - or even better: properly solving your problem - because legitimate clients would cache the 301 redirect and therefore not be able to login to your website anymore.

> Will my Server IP also be black listed? Or at any risk? (Because i'm the one who redirecting to them.)

No.

> Or is it legitimate to do?

Yes.

> will the other destination be aware of my Server IP

The destination will see your domain name in the Referer field

Source: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt